# How to validate JSON being sent using Struts2 JSON Plugin without throwing exception

Tags: java, json, struts2, query-string, struts2-json-plugin

Suppose there's a `Double` variable in an action, and if the value sent in the request body is something like

```
{"dblField":""}
```

and the `interceptorStack` looks like :

```xml
<action name="save" class="actions.MyAction" method="save">
    <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack">
    </interceptor-ref>
    <!--<interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>-->
   <!-- I've tried using each of the above two separately, but both failed -->
    <interceptor-ref name="json">
        <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    
    <result type="json" name="*">
        <param name="excludeProperties">
            idIo
        </param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Then the action throws a `NumberFormatException`, which is fine according to the plugin source code [here](https://github.com/apache/struts2/blob/STRUTS_2_3_15_X/plugins/json/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONPopulator.java).

But this exception is not handled in the plugin and hence, returns from the action throwing exception, which results in the firing of `global-exception-handler`.

If the same request was sent using a query-string, `?dblField=` then the action returns `INPUT`.

So, how can I make the json-plugin behave in the same way to return `INPUT` and set appropriate `fieldErrors` instead of throwing `NumberFormatException` and firing the `globalExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2):

You could place [`exception` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/exception-interceptor.html) before your own interceptor instead of the [`json` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/) by extending `json` interceptor and override `intercept` method where you can catch errors. Then you can either add action errors or rethrow a custom exception which you can map in the action config or globally.

```
<exception-mapping exception="org.exceptionmapping.CustomException"
                             result="errorresult"/>
```

This way you can map all json only interceptor errors with your custom exception.

Comment: It's different. Validate() is not the one which is calling the jsonToObject converter, that's done by the JSON interceptor, which throws NumberFormatException because of blank double value.

Comment: It too much work, if I had to write a validation interceptor before the JSON interceptor, instead the JSON interceptor or the json-validation interceptor should add Errors, rather than throwing Exception which is then handled by globalExceptionHandler. I'm also working on creating a SSCCE that'll help to greatly understand the situation.

Comment: I can't check for errors, because the JSON interceptor throws a NFE and the action code is never executed. Even though a double is passed a string, it shouldn't throw Exception instead return INPUT, adding the error to fieldErrors. Is there any other means to check for errors ?

Comment: finally, I ended up writing my own JSONInterceptor, but that's not good, since it's unable to log/add fieldErrors. It'll work for now, I've filed it as a bug, let's see what those guys think

Comment: finally, I've finished with JSON validation framework which could be integrated whatsoever in the application via extension point or via filter or interceptor.